# CRITICAL WARNING: Python Version Compiled Incorrectly using Miniconda and Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, conda, jupyter-lab

I recently used the Windows x64 Miniconda installer to install Miniconda. I created a new conda environment that uses `Python 3.11.2`. Running `jupyter lab` from inside the conda env yields the following error:

```
This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled
(internal generated filenames are not absolute).
```

I see that https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/issues/213 Guido Van Rossum suggests passing `-Xfrozen_modules=off` for the python debugger but I am unaware how to do this when launching jupyter lab. The issue suggestions seem to be specifically for PyCharm users or anyone with access to a launch.json (probably VSCode users).

Anyone know if this fix still works and how to implement it running jupyter lab in conda command prompt?